# What if the gcd between two polynomials is 1

Tags: ideals, gcd-and-lcm

I have this exercise in $A=Z[x]/(x^2-2, 7)$ and I have to say if $A$ is a field or not.
I know that I should show that the ideal generated by the gcd of the polynomial is maximal but i can't see how to prove that. It seems to me that the gcd is $1$, if so what should I conclude?

Comment: $\Bbb Z[x]$ isn't a Bézout domain, therefore it's entirely possible that $\langle \operatorname{gcd}(p,q)\rangle\supsetneq \langle p,q\rangle$.

Comment: so, what should i do to show A is a field?

Comment: @Christie The third isomorphism theorem is your friend, I think.

Comment: I see your point, but the fact is that the solution i have for this exercise says that A is NOT a field, but i can't see why...

Comment: Can you prove that $\langle x^2-2,7 \rangle \subsetneq \langle x^2-2,7,x \rangle$? If so, then $\langle x^2-2,7 \rangle$ isn't a maximal ideal, so the quotient is not a field

Comment: @MarioGonzales Today only works if $\langle x^2-2,7,x\rangle\neq\langle 1\rangle$.

Comment: *That, not "Today". Damn mobile keyboard.

Comment: You're right sorry, it was only an idea, I didn't prove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have an isomorphism
$$\Bbb Z[X]/(X^2-2,7) \cong (\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)[X]/(X^2-2)$$ so we reduced to the question whether $(X^2-2)$ is a maximal ideal in the PID $(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)[X]=\Bbb F_7[X]$, hence whether $X^2-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_7$. This (or better the contrapositive) is equivalent to the question whether $2$ has a square root in $\Bbb F_7$, which is indeed the case. So $X^2-2$ is **not** irreducible over $\Bbb F_7$, the ideal $(X^2-2)$ is **not** maximal in $\Bbb F_7[X]$ and hence $\Bbb Z[X]/(X^2-2,7)$ is **not** a field.

Comment: Oh that sounds great, thank you!

Comment: @Cristie After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).